# Mapbox - What are my layer ID's?

Tags: html, mapbox

I'm new to using Mapbox.

I'm trying to add a new layer to my map that is above the water layer but below labels.

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'maine',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'maine',
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#088',
        'fill-opacity': 0.8
    }
}, 'water');
```

(This code was taken from some example code from Mapbox.)

Right now, this creates a layer that is below the water layer and the labels. However, I can't figure out what layer ID would bring it above the water layer.

This is the stylesheet I'm using:

```
mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9
```

How do I find the other valid layer ID's for this style sheet? I've tried 'streets', 'roads', 'road', 'land', etc, but nothing has worked. I thought this link included all the layer names:

https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/mapbox/light-v9/

but the only one that keeps my new layer from just being on top of everything is 'water'. Help!

Comment: If my question doesn't help, can you post a live sample of your code?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve style specifications [from the styles api](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/styles/#retrieve-a-style).

For example to get all the layer_ids on the light-v10 style you could do this in python:

```
import requests    
for layer in requests.get('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10?access_token=API_TOKEN').json()['layers']: print(layer['id'])
```

Which yields:

```
land
landcover
national-park
landuse
water-shadow
waterway
water
hillshade
land-structure-polygon
land-structure-line
aeroway-polygon
aeroway-line
building-outline
building
tunnel-street-minor-low
tunnel-street-minor-case
tunnel-primary-secondary-tertiary-case
tunnel-major-link-case
tunnel-motorway-trunk-case
tunnel-construction
tunnel-path
tunnel-steps
tunnel-major-link
tunnel-pedestrian
tunnel-street-minor
tunnel-primary-secondary-tertiary
tunnel-motorway-trunk
road-pedestrian-case
road-minor-low
road-street-low
road-minor-case
road-street-case
road-secondary-tertiary-case
road-primary-case
road-major-link-case
road-motorway-trunk-case
road-construction
road-path
road-steps
road-major-link
road-pedestrian
road-minor
road-street
road-secondary-tertiary
road-primary
road-motorway-trunk
road-rail
bridge-pedestrian-case
bridge-street-minor-low
bridge-street-minor-case
bridge-primary-secondary-tertiary-case
bridge-major-link-case
bridge-motorway-trunk-case
bridge-construction
bridge-path
bridge-steps
bridge-major-link
bridge-pedestrian
bridge-street-minor
bridge-primary-secondary-tertiary
bridge-motorway-trunk
bridge-rail
bridge-major-link-2-case
bridge-motorway-trunk-2-case
bridge-major-link-2
bridge-motorway-trunk-2
admin-1-boundary-bg
admin-0-boundary-bg
admin-1-boundary
admin-0-boundary
admin-0-boundary-disputed
road-label
waterway-label
natural-line-label
natural-point-label
water-line-label
water-point-label
poi-label
airport-label
settlement-subdivision-label
settlement-label
state-label
country-label
```

*I would just add a note of caution that the layer ids for the default styles can change significantly version to version.*

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment in Mapbox.com/studio by adding your `maine` tile set into a new style, then you can move the layer interactively to experiment and proof the effect that you want.

The second parameter for `addLayer` is `before`, so your `maine` source should've gone before the `water` layer.  See the docs on `addLayer` for details

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#addLayer

---

The names of the layers are identified by `"id"` in the Style.json.

You can find the names of the layers by going to the link you posted

- https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/mapbox/light-v9/
  there you will see a nice visualization of the layer ids from Mapbox.

The `water` layer is near the bottom of the layers stack of the Mapbox light style.

Here are the layers with water in the `"id`.

```
        "id": "waterway-river-canal",
        "id": "water shadow",
        "id": "water",
        "id": "waterway-label",
        "id": "water-label",
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layer ID can be found by opening your map in Mapbox Studio. If you go to `View style details` (the box with an arrow in the top right corner of the left hand window, it will reveal all the layers.